# Community college transcript

Tags: transcript-of-records, community-college

A while ago I messed up my community college transcript with withdrawing from classes frequently due to certain circumstances. But I actually do enjoy school, learning, and want to rectify what has been done etc- yet this transcript is pretty messed up from the past and I don’t know what to do going forward.

I did well in all my classes I did stay in getting a Bs or As
BUT these Ws are killing me.

I’m moving to a new state soon and need to continue school out there.
I know there’s not necessarily a way to “start fresh” but any advice would help as to how I can try to clean up my mess I’ve made in the past with my withdrawals.

I know I can apply for academic forgiveness - but don’t know how much that could help me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. What problem are you trying to "rectify" (i.e., why are the Ws a problem for you)? What is "academic forgiveness"? Are you in the US? Is the problem that you are applying for undergraduate admission and keep getting denied?

Comment: Haha sorry, I must have been almost half asleep trying to condense a lifetime of words. I want to try and rectify my transcript- I know there is not a way to officially do that In the US where I’m based- but I know I can apply for academic forgiveness and “remove” some bad terms I had. I’m doing better moving forward, but have a few hiccups on my records which I think could hinder my chances of getting in anywhere if I were to apply which I have not done yet. I need to finish a few more classes - but the classes I did stay in those few terms I did well in other than my Ws

Comment: OK, so it sounds like you are applying to another institution where you can finish your undergraduate work. We don't take questions on undergrad admissions, just because admissions officers are not "academic staff" and so we don't really have any expertise to offer in that area. But, a few reactions: (1) there is no such concept of "academic forgiveness." Maybe your institution has a policy of removing bad grades from transcripts under certain circumstances, and that's great if so. But this is unusual.

Comment: (2) If you have mostly As and Bs, I wouldn't worry too much about withdrawals. Just explain the circumstances behind the withdrawals in your admissions materials.  Getting into the top colleges is always a challenge, but I seriously doubt you won't be able to get into college at all. (3) Bad grades also have a way of "aging out." If your transcript has Ws or bad grades from 5+ years ago, that will count a lot less than more recent activities. But, you should explain in your application what you've been doing recently. Good luck.